# Looking for File based caching or storage libraries

Tags: c#, .net, caching, .net-2.0, storage

Here are my requirements:

- The mechanism or the library to be used should be fast & performant
- Wonderful if it has been proven enterprise ready
- Can provide some sort of Interface or contract to retrieve data
- Works well with C#, .NET 2.0

btw there were similar questions but none addressed the question i wanted answered.

#### Context

I had developed Custom Membership and Profile providers for **Single Sign-On applications** all working well & good, it is just that we want to persist the certain user information across applications (this would be possible only when session state is stored on SQLServer DB) through session but we never want to go that way. Also we use the **UserId** and mostly the **primary keys** as starting point to do CRUD operations.

#### More about application...

So each time a CRUD is performed i should do `Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey` which hit's the database for retrieving the Id for the user( i could cache this but again will lose this when navigating to other applications, also i got many others entities that needs same treatment).

#### My thoughts

I am certainly sure there are some libraries, proven methods that i can use here. In the sense

1. First load is from database
2. The data loaded is stored in global file repository(a file i suppose) outside the virtual directory or somewhere using Key-value pairs or Relational system.
3. Subsequent requests are made to this file and data is retrieved.(When a key is not found a Sql server command is run to retrieve the value which is again stored in this file)

#### Question

Suggestions for Fast,File based,Atomic,Storage mechanism or Library(Something like memcached but does the storing on Files) that works on .NET 2.0.

Comment: Can you add a specific question?

Comment: @NevilleK Updated the Question to include what i really wanted as answer.

Comment: Depending on your budget, have you considered Windows Azure? If you are want to read / write files with good fast access, you might want to look at the Azure Content Delivery Network (CDN).

Comment: What performance exactly are you trying to improve by introducing this cache?  Are the queries complex and you don't want to run them again?  Or is the network slow, and you don't want to tranport that information again?  Are you sure you're solving a real problem?

Comment: Open source C# implementations comparison on http://csharptest.net/586/bplustree-benchmarks-and-comparisons/ Focus on BPlusTree and STSdb.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Queries are complex (with all the fine tuning done) also just to get the ID of the user is a query required? i am certainly sure u would say no.

Comment: I would also say that just to get the the ID of the user, you shouldn't even read from a file.  Critical information that is used constantly should be cached in memory, not in a file.  And if you want to share that with other applications, they could read it once, but each should cache it in memory separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the time you are trying to optimize is the effort in querying and composing the information in memory rather than the time to transfer that information from the SQL server, you might consider using SQL as your cache mechanism as well.  Just create a record with a varbinary(max) column to store your serialized data for the current session, and some unique ID that identifies that session (if you have multiple sessions).  What you might end up with is a 2-stage cache -- if this application has loaded the information into memory, you an use it; if not, you can query the cached SQL record; if that doesn't exist, you can perform your full querying to create it.

**Edit:** I also advise that you consider the [Optimize Later](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OptimizeLater) philosophy if you haven't already.  Encapsulate your object that provides this data and optimize it as necessary.

Comment: it is the hits to the database also that we want to save.But seems projects like http://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/ are valid candidates as answer. U got any other suggestions that the above project

Comment: Are you trying to share information on a client among multiple applications without each application having to query the database for the same information separately?  Would it make sense to have a local (SQL Express perhaps?) database to fulfill this purpose?

Comment: I guess I still don't fully understand why you are trying to out-perform the database server unless it's on a remote client and you want something local. But it seems to me that you already have a file-based storage library (the database server) and you don't believe that it's adequately performant. Have you proven it? Are you sure you're not trying to optimize too early?  After all SQL Server fulfills all your requirements doesn't it?

Comment: Now i am confused as to how to the put the question, u did understand the part of it exactly as i wanted but not the part why i prefer other storage media than the sql database.

Comment: If you can't explain why a particular solution isn't right, maybe you need to reconsider your assumption that it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're talking about a web application.  Have you considered the new [HTML5 Web Storage](http://sixrevisions.com/html/introduction-web-storage/) API's suitability for your case?  The potential problems (reasons it would not be suitable) would be: 1 - Can't require clients to have HTML5; 2 - Information is needed primarily on the server, not the client.

Comment: yup that's a web application. didn't i put that in question.. let me see hmmmm ooh my what a mistake. will ammend